# Fix the error: "TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable" with out changing my_list['push_first'](x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am writing a code for a make_mutable_rlist.
I am running in to an error where it says:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nadav\Documents\GitHub\nadavEX3Python\main.py", line 61, in <module>
    my_list['push_first'](x)
    ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable"
```

I don't want to change the line my_list'push_first' and want to leave it as is.

The code that I wrote is

```
empty_rlist = None


def make_rlist(first, rest):
    """Make a recursive list from its first element and the rest."""
    def dispatch(message, value=None):
        if message == 'getitem':
            if value == 0:
                return first
            return rest('getitem', value - 1)
    return dispatch


def make_mutable_rlist():
    """Return a functional implementation of a mutable recursive list."""
    contents = empty_rlist

    def dispatch(message, value=None):
        nonlocal contents
        if message == 'len':
            return len_rlist(contents)
        elif message == 'getitem':
            return getitem_rlist(contents, value)
        elif message == 'push_first':
            contents = make_rlist(value, contents)
        elif message == 'pop_first':
            f = first(contents)
            contents = rest(contents)
            return f
        elif message == 'str':
            return str(contents)
    return dispatch, contents


def len_rlist(s):
    """Return the length of recursive list s."""
    length = 0
    while s != empty_rlist:
        s, length = rest(s), length + 1
    return length


def getitem_rlist(s, i):
    """Return the element at index i of recursive list s."""
    while i > 0:
        s, i = rest(s), i - 1
    return first(s)


def first(s):
    """Return the first element of a recursive list s."""
    return s('getitem', 0)

def rest(s):
    """Return the rest of the elements of a recursive list s."""
    return s('getitem', 1)


my_list = make_mutable_rlist()[0]
for x in range(4):
    my_list['push_first'](x)

print(my_list("len"))
```

Changing the my_list'push_first' to my_list('push_first', x) works but I want to keep it the same and not change the **main** part of the code.

Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Then your `make_mutable_rlist` needs to not return a single function but a dictionary with a function for each `message`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `make_mutable_rlist()[0]` that you assign to `my_list` ?

```py
def make_mutable_rlist():
    """Return a functional implementation of a mutable recursive list."""
    contents = empty_rlist

    def dispatch(message, value=None):
        nonlocal contents
        if message == 'len':
            return len_rlist(contents)
        elif message == 'getitem':
            return getitem_rlist(contents, value)
        elif message == 'push_first':
            contents = make_rlist(value, contents)
        elif message == 'pop_first':
            f = first(contents)
            contents = rest(contents)
            return f
        elif message == 'str':
            return str(contents)
    return dispatch, contents
```

this function always returns a tuple of size 2, containing a `dispatch` function and a `contents` value.

You can't index (i.e. `foo["something"]`) on a tuple. As @luk2302 suggested in a comment, this is typically a `dict` behavior, and considering your `dispatch` method that may be what is expected.

But as your `dispatch` function takes an optional `value` parameter, it does not work well with indexing.

I think you should return a `Dict[str, Function[Optional[Any], Any]]`, which would look like so :

```py
def make_mutable_rlist():
    contents = empty_rlist
    dispatch = {
        "len": len_rlist(contents),
        "getitem": lambda value: getitem_rlist(contents, value),
        "push_first": lambda value: make_rlist(value, contents),
        "pop_first": [first(contents), rest(contents)][0],  # lambda abuse to do 2 things
        "str": str(contents)
    }
    return dispatch, contents
```

But I think you will stumble on another problem later on : even in your original code you reassign the `contents` that was closure'd by the inner `dispatch`, but it won't change the value that was previously returned, that's the difference between *values* and *references* (respectively *immutable* and *mutable* in Python). Which warrants another question on this site :)